# Cannot create new database diagram in SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008.
Currently, I cannot create new database diagram from the SSMS 2008 on an SQL Server 2008 instance.
Has anyone ever experienced this ? 
The problem started after I tried to install Visual Studio 11 Beta, and apparently the Beta also installs SQL Server 2012 RC0. Now I have uninstalled the Visual Studio 11 Beta and the SQL Server 2012 that goes along with it.

EDIT :
Error message that shows when I tried to create new database diagrams is : "The specified module could not be found (MS Visual Database Tools)"

Comment: Is there an error message?  A menu choice gone missing?  A paralyzing fear?

Comment: yes there is, the error message is "The specified module could not be found (MS Visual Database Tools)"

Comment: Did you try unistalling and reinstalling SQL Server 2008 Client Tools? (Particularly Administration or Management tools). Excuse me but I have SQL Server in a foreing language, so the wording can be inexact. Whenever I had trouble with SQL Server I did this (i.e working with SSMS 205 side by side with SSMS 2008). It always worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but never found an explanation of what was wrong. I ended up uninstalling SQL Server 2012, uninstalling Visual Studio 11 Beta, and then reinstalling the Visual Studio 11 Beta (keeping SQL Server 2008). I can now create DB diagrams from SSMS 2008, but not from within Visual Studio 11 Beta (I don't think Visual Studio 11 Beta supports the feature, at least not for SQL Server 2008).

Comment: Did you install VS 2011 beta without installing SQL Server 2012?

Comment: I did not reinstall SQL Server 2012. I just wanted a setup that worked at the time.

Comment: Can you choose which components to install? Because when I tried to install, there is no options to choose the components.